# Loopbackjs: Followers and Followees Model (Twitter-like)

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'd like to create a Twitter-like model but can't manage to make it working:

User's model so far:

```
 {
   "name": "NsUser",
   "base": "User",
 ...
    "relations": {
        "followers": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "User",
          "through": "Follow",
          "foreignKey": "followerUserId"
        },
        "followees": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "User",
          "through": "Follow",
          "foreignKey": "followeeUserId"
        }
    }
}
```

Follow's model so far:

```
{
  "name": "Follow",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
...
  "relations": {
    "followee": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "NsUser",
      "foreignKey": "followeeUserId"
    },
    "follower": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "NsUser",
      "foreignKey": "followerUserId"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I add a relation in the Follow model:

```
{
    "created": "2016-08-19T09:23:18.175Z",
    "id": "57b6d0068d55e5368538c8f4",
    "followeeUserId": "578f7ad2ba0bfc40d78ef985",
    "followerUserId": "5790bb3172e2738deb7532ee"
  }
```

But cannot get the result in http://0.0.0.0:3008/api/NsUsers/5790bb3172e2738deb7532ee/followers
Here is the crash:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Relation \"user\" is not defined for Follow model",
    "stack": "Error: Relation \"user\" is not defined for Follow model\n    at processIncludeItem ....
  }
}
```

I dig a little and found there was a problem similar here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/394

But it seems I need loop-back-datasource-juggler >= 2.18.0 but I run

```
 npm update loopback-datasource-juggler
 npm -v loopback-datasource-juggler
```

It tells me: `2.10.1`

Maybe it's the only problem (do I really get the latest version??), or maybe it's my Model which is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined relation model wrongly. `Follow` model has relation to `NsUser`, but in `NsUser`, you defined relation to `user`.

Please change like this :

```
"relations": {
        "followers": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "NsUser",
          "through": "Follow",
          "foreignKey": "followerUserId"
        },
        "followees": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "NsUser",
          "through": "Follow",
          "foreignKey": "followeeUserId"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Too bad I wasn't able to see this...
I finally ended with
"followers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "NsUser",
      "foreignKey": "followeeUserId",
      "through": "Follow",
      "keyThrough": "followerUserId"
    },
    "followees": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "NsUser",
      "foreignKey": "followerUserId",
      "through": "Follow",
      "keyThrough": "followeeUserId"
    }

Answer (score 1):

This question seems like a problem with NPM, not really a loopback problem.  The npm page for [loopback-datasource-juggler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-datasource-juggler) shows the latest version is 2.49.0.

I'd guess the problem has to do with your (or perhaps a another module) `package.json` file describing the dependency for this.  Try looking into your `package.json` file first.